# In C++, after opening a .txt file with values, reading the file gives me ""

Tags: c++, ifstream, readfile

Here's my code.

```
ifstream readFile;
readFile.open("voltages.txt");

if (readFile.fail( ) )
{
    cout << "\nCould not open the file ... check to see if voltages.txt exists\n";
    system("pause");
    return;
}

string tempString = "";
//readFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
int idx = 0;
if (readFile.is_open())
{
    while ( readFile.good() )
    {
        getline(readFile,tempString);
        cout << tempString << endl;
    }
    readFile.close();
}
```

If I move the voltages.txt to c:/, then it works fine, but I have it in the same folder as my .exe right now, and when I set a breakpoint at cout << tempString << endl; it shows up just as "".  I'd like to keep it in the .exe if possible.  As you can see I tried seeking to the beginning, with no luck.  Please help this C++ noob!  Thank you!

Comment: How many lines does it read when voltages.txt is not in C:/ ?

Comment: It just reads in one line, which is ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be because you are trying to read a local file when the program requires a link to the file from C:/

You can test this by replacing `voltages.txt` with `C:/pathToVoltages/voltages.txt`

I would suggest passing the file to your executable by doing this:

```
int main(int argc, char argv[]){
    ifstream readFile;
    readFile.open(argv[2]);
    /*Rest of the code*/
```

This assumes the path to the file is given by the first argument you give to the program as in:

```
./program pathToFile/voltages.txt
```

Hope this helps